# SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal.getName() returns "ANONYMOUS"

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, extjs, sessioncontext

In my Java EE application, I declare the following restful class

```
@Path("userProfile")
@Stateless
public class UserProfileRestful {

   @Resource
   private SessionContext sessionContext;

   @Path("userName")
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.Text_Palin)
   public String findCurrentUserName(){
      return sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal.getName();
   }

}
```

aiming to get the username of the currently logged-in user through any client.

After I logged in with username "myuser", I just pasted the following url to the web browser in a new tab

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest/userProfile/userName
```

and the displayed response was as expected : "myuser".

Now I tried to get that username from within another ExtJS application (that requires no authentication) performing an Ajax request as follows :

```
Ext.Ajax.Request({
   url : "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest/userProfile/userName",
   success : function(response,options){
      alert('username : ' + response.responseText);
   },
   failure : function(){
      alert('request failed');
   }

});
```

the alerted result was "ANONYMOUS", even though I'm still logged in as "myuser" during the same session.

So,why does the caller principal change in the 2nd case, and is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,Its done...

The idea is that

```
   sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal.getName()
```

depends on the context of the caller (client), practically on which application server is it running.

My ExtJS application (the client side) was first running on Jitty server, whereas the Java EE application (the server side) was running on GlassFish .

Two different application servers and consequently two different contexts was the problem.

Clearly...after I deployed both applications on glassfish, eveything went right.